# The main menu doesn't load with correct permissions assigned (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm developing a windows form application with C# and the issue is as follows.

The requirement is to change properties in my main menu items (Ex: Make certain menu strip items invisible, etc.), according to the role of logged-in users (Ex: The main menu of a student shouldn't contain the "Lecturer" menu strip item)

The code for my login form is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DBL;

namespace Interfaces
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string UserID;
        public string Password;
        public string Role;


        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM LoginInfo";

            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection con;
            connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-U9V5QGE\CL_HNDCSE_86_16;Initial Catalog=UNIMAP_WAD;Integrated Security=True";
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            SqlDataReader sqlDReader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            UserID = txtUserID.Text;
            Password = txtPassword.Text;


            while (sqlDReader.Read())
            {
                Role = sqlDReader["Role"].ToString();
            }

            if (UserID == sqlDReader["UserID"].ToString() && Password == sqlDReader["Password"].ToString())
            {

                con.Close();

                if (Role == "SuperAdmin")
                {
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInUID = UserID;
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInRole = Role;

                    frmMainMenu objmainmenu = new frmMainMenu();
                    objmainmenu.Show();


                }
                else if (Role == "Admin")
                {
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInUID = UserID;
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInRole = Role;

                    frmMainMenu objmainmenu = new frmMainMenu();
                    objmainmenu.Show();

                    objmainmenu.credentialsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                }
                else if (Role == "StudentCoordinator")
                {
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInUID = UserID;
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInRole = Role;

                    frmMainMenu objmainmenu = new frmMainMenu();
                    objmainmenu.Show();

                    objmainmenu.credentialsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    objmainmenu.lecturerToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                }

                else if (Role == "Lecturer")
                {
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInUID = UserID;
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInRole = Role;

                    frmMainMenu objmainmenu = new frmMainMenu();
                    objmainmenu.Show();

                    objmainmenu.credentialsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    objmainmenu.studentToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;

                }

                else if (Role == "Student")
                {
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInUID = UserID;
                    CurrentCredentials.LoggedInRole = Role;

                    frmMainMenu objmainmenu = new frmMainMenu();
                    objmainmenu.Show();

                    objmainmenu.credentialsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
                    objmainmenu.lecturerToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Also, using a static class "CurrentCredentials" to store the current users' User ID and Role.
Resides in the Class Library "DBL".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DBL;

namespace DBL
{
    public static class CurrentCredentials
    {
        private static string _LoggedInUID;
        private static string _LoggedInRole;


        public static String LoggedInUID
        {

            get
            {
                return _LoggedInUID;
            }
            set
            {
                _LoggedInUID = value;
            }

        }

        public static String LoggedInRole
        {
            get
            {
                return _LoggedInRole;
            }
            set
            {
                _LoggedInRole = value;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

You may see that I've changed the properties from the Login code itself. I've made changes to the Main menu > menu strip items (private > public), so I can access those from anywhere in the program.

Additionally, just now received this error on the following part of the login screen.

```
//error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

//received from the line
if (UserID == sqlDReader["UserID"].ToString() && Password == sqlDReader["Password"].ToString())
```

Your expertise provided in this matter is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant the part

```
if (UserID == sqlDReader["UserID"].ToString() && Password == sqlDReader["Password"].ToString())...
```

to be in the while loop? If it is after the while loop you cannot access the sqldreader as there is no more data left to read.

Comment: Thanks mate. I believe it worked.

But now it displays the "Invalid credentials" message everytime, even when I enter correct credentials.

Comment: You are selecting all users from the db and then if the first one is not the logged in user you show the messagebox. Just select the one user with the UserID in the SQL query.

Comment: `"SELECT UserID, Password, Role FROM LoginInfo WHERE UserID = '"+UserID+"'"`  Updated the SQL query to the above and still receiving the "Invalid Credentials" message. The variable UserID contains the client entered user id

Comment: Then maybe "Role" does not contain one of the values you are handlig in your code? Use your debugger and see whats going on.